# Pillow module doesn't import correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, python-import

I'm making a program that requires to check a certain pixel on the screen, to check what color it was, and it seems like Pillow was good for this, however when I tried to import it (Yes I did install it using pip), I get this error:

`ImportError: No module named Pillow`

I've tried all of these imports:

```
import PIL
import Pillow
import pillow
from Pillow import Image
from PIL import Image
from PIL import *
from Pillow import *
```

But all of them return an error of "No module named x"
When I try to install Pillow using PIP I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (6.1.0)
```

I have also installed Image using PIP as well:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Image) (6.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: django in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Image) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django->Image) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref~=3.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django->Image) (3.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django->Image) (0.3.1)
```

If there are other modules I could use that would be good for this I would be open to hear about those as it specifically doesn't need to be Pillow, it just seemed like the best one to use. Anyone know why this doesn't seem to import correctly?

Comment: From what I see: `import PIL` should work as is. Are you sure the `pip` install is for Python2 or Python3?

Comment: What does `python -m pip list` print? *(where `python` is the same interpreter as used to run the import)*

Comment: @KlausD., that prints:
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip

Comment: Then, your pip version is not installed on the main Python interpreter. Use `pip -V` to check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many possibilities as to what is going wrong. You are on a Mac, so you could be using:

- Apple-supplied Python 2.7, which has no corresponding `pip` and is obsolete
- Apple-supplied Python 3.7, which does have a `pip`
- homebrew Python 3
- homebrew Python 2 and is obsolete

So, the first thing you need to do is say **how** you start your Python, so if you type `python3` to start Python, then you need to provide the output of running:

```
type python3        # or "type python" if you start Python by typing "python"
```

If you type `pip3` to start `pip`, you need to provide the output of running:

```
type pip3           # or "type pip" if you start pip by typing "pip"
```

Then you (and we) will know what Python/pip combination you are intending to use. Once that is clear, you should get in the habit of using a shebang to select the correct Python that you are targeting, so your script should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import this, that
...
```

for example, if you want to target Python3.

Once that is clear, the correct `import` statement is:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: for type python3:
```python3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3```

for type pip3:
```pip3 is hashed (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3)```

And im using visual studio code and I selected my interpreter using that so I believe I wouldnt have to use the #!, but I may be wrong so correct me if so

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, no clue what happened but I tried importing again and it seems to work now. Even installing it using pip3 said requirement already satisfied every time and I didnt change interpreter either. Maybe I was importing it wrong not sure